# Has Chris Nolan commented officially on the theme of Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

Chris Nolan has previously stated that the main theme of Batman Begins is Fear, and the main theme of The Dark Knight is Chaos. Has he officially stated what the theme of Dark Knight Rises is?

iMDB.com states in the Trivia section for DKR that the theme of the movie is Pain, but I didn't see that in the actual movie as much as Fear was in BB or Chaos in TDK.

> Honestly, the main theme I noticed throughout the movie was Despair.

Was the trivia on iMDB right, and if so, can someone please provide a link that verifies it? iMDB is usually fairly accurate, but it does suffer from wiki-rot, especially on newer movies.

If iMDB was wrong, **has Chris Nolan said what the theme really is?**

Answer (score 8):

According to [digitalspy.ca](http://www.digitalspy.ca/movies/news/a392264/christopher-nolan-the-theme-of-dark-knight-rises-is-consequences.html,), "the theme of Dark Knight Rises is consequences". When asked if pain could be a motif, he said yes, but then added that, in the film, "There's a lot about the consequences of actions".